# disable an input field after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am configuring a chatbot and I want to give the user three options to choose from. The user will choose the option by clicking the buttons; this means if button 1 was clicked, the input field 1 will be shown in the next instance (same html file). If butt[image]on 2 was clicked, the input field 2 will be shown etc.

In the first image the user should choose an intention and according to their intention one of the input fields should disappear in the second image.

I have tried to do with show and hide configurations of CSS and JavaScript. However it did not work. Could anyone suggest me a solution? The trick is that one can not use show and hide div method, because the input field is not shown at the same time as the button but after one selects an option. Thank you in advance!

Here is some code:

```js
function faqact() {
  var x = document.getElementById("python");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select2_el").select2({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button id="faqact" onclick="faqact()" type="button">I just want to ask a question</button>
  <button id="alexact" type="button">I want to make the BOT do something for me!</button>
  <button id="connectact" type="button">I want to connect to a human asap!</button>
</div>
different input fields because if the button 1 is clicked, i want the javascript to connect to python through flask.

<div id="conversation" class="chat-input hide">
  <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message..."> -->
  <form id="chatform" style="margin-top: 10px" onsubmit="return pushChat();">
    <textarea type="text" id="wisdom" size="80" value="" placeholder="I need a hotel room"> </textarea>
    <div class="input-action-icon">
      <button type="submit" id="completed-task" class="fabutton" onsubmit="return pushChat();">
                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>

<div id="python" class="chat-input hide">
  <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message..."> -->
  <form id="pythonform" style="margin-top: 10px" onsubmit="return pushChat();">
    <textarea type="text" id="faq" size="80" value="" placeholder="I need a hotel room"> </textarea>
    <div class="input-action-icon">
      <button type="submit" id="pythonsend" class="fabutton" onsubmit="return pushChat();">
                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

[image: In the first image, i give the user to choose their intention and in the second image one of the input fields should disappear]

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a runnable [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/82548); could you [edit] your question to take care of the reported errors (by linking the `select2` plugin as a minimum)?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're basically wanting a radio group to control visibility associated to a button, kind of like below for a quick proof of concept. Cheers.

```css
label {
  background-color: #0f0;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input, div, textarea {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-color: #00f;
  color: #fff;
}

#btn1:checked ~ #btn1input {
  display: block;
}
#btn2:checked ~ #btn2input {
  display: block;
}
#btn3:checked ~ #btn3input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="btn1" type="radio" name="test">
<label for="btn1" type="button">Ask a question or something.</label>
<input id="btn2" type="radio" name="test">
<label for="btn2" type="button">Make bot do something.</label>
<input id="btn3" type="radio" name="test">
<label for="btn3" type="button">Talk to a human</label>

<hr>

<input id="btn1input" type="text" placeholder="Ask your question">
<div id="btn2input">
<button>bot stuff1</button><button>bot stuff2</button>
</div>
<textarea id="btn3input" placeholder="Talk to a human"></textarea>
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added some pictures for clarity. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @hurricane made minor adjustments to mimic your ask more.

Comment: hi, have copy pasted your solution and it does not work in the chatbot. I click the radio button so it is selected, and click start chat and than nothing happens. no textarea no div all of them are not displayed.

Comment: one has to somehow save the selection of the radio button and after one clicks start, than the command of radio button should be executed; such as show or hide a div, but do not know how to do it

Comment: It sounds like you just need to grab the element at the instance to ref like blah.getElementById or whatever and wire up the event handling. I only supplied a quickie proof of concept to accomplish your ux, wiring it into your code would require...well, the code. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute readonly in input field.

so your if statement in javascript should be like this:
(here x is id of your input field)

```
var x= Id_Of_InputField

if (x.hasAttribute("readonly")) {
    x.removeAttribue("readonly")
  } 
else {
    x.addAttribute("readonly")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it with jquery. I have made out of my buttons radio buttons and finally used the below script to solve my issue:

```
$('#startchat').click(function() {
   if($('#radiobutton').is(':checked')) { $("#python").show(); }
});
```

Thank you all for your support